# Racket: "string-ith" not working in normal Racket

Tags: racket

I am using `(string-ith "hello" 3)` in `Geiser` environment within `Emacs`. It is showing an error

```
string-ith: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
  in module: top-level
  context...:
   eval-one-top
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/repl.rkt:11:26
```

I tried the same thing in **Dr.Racket** IDE.  Using the default `#lang racket`, it is throwing the same error,

```
> (string-ith "hello" 3)
. . string-ith: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
>
```

but with changing the language to `beginning student`, it is working properly.

```
> (string-ith "hello" 3)
"l"
>
```

I tried with  `(require racket/string)` but of no use.

I am finding it difficult working with `racket`. Can anyone clarify the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply that the procedure isn't predefined in those languages, as the errors say. It's provided in Beginning Student as a convenience.

If you want it, then use an existing procedure like `substring` to define it yourself. Or, if you're less motivated, [this page](https://www.brinckerhoff.org/clements/2182-csc430/Labs/lab1.html) suggests a way to import it.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess the normal way to use it is `string-ref` function.